# How can I create a subclass of a message (.msg) in OMNeT++?

Tags: c++, parent-child, omnet++

I'm wondering whether it's possible to create a subclass of a message declaration (file *.msg which extends cPacket, see [OMNeT++ Simulation Library](http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classcPacket.html)). What I've tried so far is:

```
packet childPacket : parentPacket{...}
```

and

```
parentPacket childPacket {...}
```

which both can't be compiled by *opp_msgc*.

Thus, I haven't found a way so far to achieve this and I'm very thankful for any hints.

Cheers 
- alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is really simple and most probably it just shows my lack of knowledge in c++ (I thought 'extend' was just used in java)...

Finally, I could achieve my goal described above by just typing

```
packet childPacket extends parentPacket{...}
```

Oh gosh, it's hot in herre...